# Como hacer que el DateTimePicker al iniciar siempre sea 1ero del mes en curso

Tags: c#

Bien, tengo un DateTimePicker el cual deseo que al iniciar el sistema que siempre sea 1ero y que el mes sea un mes  adelantado con respecto al actual y el dia se vaya actualizando a medida que aumento o disminuyo un objeto NumericUpDown bien tengo todo excepto como hacer que el dia sea 1ero si me pueden ayudar se los agradeceria. paso los codigos que tengo;

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddMonths(1)
```

aqui aumento el mes

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();

        dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value);
        dateTimePicker1.Value = dt.AddDays(1);
```

aqui aumento a medida que el NumericUpDown lo hace 
solo me falta el setear que siempre sea inicio de mes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tomando como base el dia de hoy, podes hacer lo siguiente:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year,DateTime.Today.Month,1);
dt = dt.AddMonths(1);
```

Y en dt, vas a tener el primer dia del mes siguiente.

Lo que hice fue basarme en el dia de hoy para construir una fecha al primero del mes de hoy, y luego le sume un mes.

Y ese valor, se lo podes asignar:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = dt
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, @gbianchi